# Solution of a partial integro-differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I want to find a solution for the following equation

$$
\partial_y u(x,y) + \partial_x u(x,y) + \int_{0}^{x} r(x-x') u(x',y) dx' = 0
$$

$$
u(x,0)=0 \quad u(0,y)=\delta(y)
$$

in $(x,y) \in (0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)$

Formally this is how I would go:

Laplace transforming in $x$
$$
\partial_y \hat{u}(s,y) + (\:s + \hat{r}(s) \:)\; \hat{u}(s,y)  = \delta(y)
$$

then

$$
\hat{u}(s,y) = e^{-sy} * e^{-r(s)\:y} H(y)
$$

and (this is related to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167034/existence-of-inverse-laplace-transform))

$$
u(x,y) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ e^{-r(s)\:y}H(y) \}(x-y,y)
$$

where $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is the inverse laplace transform and $H(y)$ the Heaviside step function

Is this correct ?  I'm not very sure about solving the ODE in $\hat{u}$ in that way...